# Java compiler errors using jGRASP

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am very new to Java and got the following two errors when I compiled:

```
stringConvert3.java:29: illegal start of expression
 public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception //Main
 ^
 stringConvert3.java:57: ';' expected
private class InnerToLowerCaseString //Second class (Inner) to convert to lower case
            ^
```

The following is the code I was working . . .

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;

//java.lang.needed to perform the "squeeze" method on strings.


public class stringConvert3 //First class and actual program.
{

static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in); 
public void printEven (){
String str;

 public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception //Main
    {

    String str;

    //The following imports the 5 line test text from a saved file (test.txt).
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new FileReader("c:\\test.txt"));
    while (inFile.hasNextLine()){
    String line = inFile.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Scan = %s\n", line);

        String save;
        save = line;
        str = save;
        System.out.printf ("Receive: <%s>\n", str);

             InnerToLowerCaseString innerString = this.new InnerToLowerCaseString ();
             str = InnerToLowerCaseString.lowerCase (str);
             str = save;
             str = trimmed (str); //Trims and abreviates.
             System.out.printf ("Trimmed: <%s>\n", str);
             str = squeeze (str); //Squeezes text.
             System.out.printf ("Squeezed: <%s>\n", str);

             if (str.length () >= 50)
             str = str.substring (0,20);
    }       

    private class InnerToLowerCaseString //Second class (Inner) to convert to lower case
    { //Brace to start the second class.

    //Following method converts all letters of String to lower case letters.

        private String lowerCase (String str)
            {
            str = str.toLowerCase();
            System.out.printf ("Convert to Lower: <%s>\n", str);
            return str;
            }

    } //Brace to end the second class.
    }

    public class threeMethods //Third class, containing three methods.
    {
        public static String trimmed (String str) //First method.
    {
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new FileReader ("c:\\test.txt"));     
            return str.trim ();
    }

    public static String trimmed (String str, int len) //Second method.
    {
        str = trimmed (str);
        if (str.length () > 10)
            return str.substring (0, 10);

        else
            return str;
    }

    public static String squeeze (String str) //Third method.
    {
        int length;

        do
        {
            length = str.length ();
            str = str.replaceAll ("  ", " "); 

            }  while (length != str.length ());  
            return (str);

    } //End of squeeze section.


} // End of the main.

}//End of stringConvert3 program.
```

Answer (score 0):

The open brace that's part of your `printEven()` method definition near the beginning of your code is never matched with a closing brace, so `main()` appears to be inside of `printEven()`. This isn't legal -- you can't define a method inside of another method -- so the compiler complains.

I looked over the rest of the code to see what other errors you have, and there are actually a lot. It almost looks like you're *deliberately* trying to define methods inside of other methods; if you are you're going to have to stop trying and implement your program correctly. Also note that an inner class defined inside a method (which is, actually, legal) cannot have an access qualifier: if you define `InnerToLowerCaseString` inside a method, then it cannot be marked `private`.

Finally, note that, despite your comment, importing `java.lang` is *never* necessary, as it's always imported implicitly. Doing it explicitly just makes your code look amateurish, so don't do it!